# Pulumi cli not available after installing it within docker image

Tags: linux, docker, pulumi

I am building a web application that makes use of the Pulumi automation SDK.  The application is to be deployed within a linux docker container, so I added the following lines to the Dockerfile:

```
RUN curl -fsSL https://get.pulumi.com | sh
ENV PATH="/root/.pulumi/bin:${PATH}"
```

However, it looks like the Pulumi CLI is not available in bash after the image is built. I have validated that the Pulumi executables were indeed installed into /root/.pulumi/bin

I suspect that the cause is pulumi installed into the /root folder rather than to ~/ but I am not sure how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: If the binaries are there, then it sounds like your container isn’t seeing your change to PATH. What happens if you run it straight from the that folder (so cd to that folder and run it)?

Comment: @PiersKarsenbarg printing the path with `echo $PATH` shows that the path does include the relevant folder (/root/.pulumi/bin).   
In addition, if I run the command`sudo  /root/.pulumi/bin/pulumi` then the Pulumi cli is invoked properly.

Comment: What error are you getting? Maybe it's a permissions thing. What user is running Pulumi? Do /root and /root/.local have a+rx permission?

Answer (score 3):

Faced the same problem and your suspicion is correct - when *Dockerfile* is being built all steps are executed as *root*. When you use the container you run as a different user.
I've ended up copying files to different folder as part of the *Dockerfile* build process:

```
RUN curl -fsSL https://get.pulumi.com | sh 
RUN mkdir /usr/bin/.pulumi && mv /root/.pulumi/* /usr/bin/.pulumi/ 
ENV PATH "$PATH:/usr/bin/.pulumi/bin/"
```

This is also ho Klotho is doing it for their docker: https://github.com/klothoplatform/docker-klotho/blob/main/Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to the same problem.

In my case, pulumi wasn't getting installed because the container image didn't have `curl` installed. The first command `curl -fsSL https://get.pulumi.com` was not retrieving the pulumi install script.

`curl` had to be installed before trying to use it.

```
RUN apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y curl; \
    curl -fsSL https://get.pulumi.com | sh;
ENV PATH="/root/.pulumi/bin:$PATH"
```